# Concurrent Stack Correctness

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

Hey I used the code below to implement concurrent stack. In the below code lock has been acquired individually for push and pop but doesn't this make Push and pop interfere with each other. In-order for a stack implementation to be correct Pop must not happen along with push but before or after push(am I correct?).But if two threads call push and pop in some order will this program preserve the order?

```
public class ConcurrentStackL
{
         object _objLock;
 
     internal class Node
    {
      internal T _item; 
         internal Node _next;
         public Node(T item, Node next) { _item = item; _next = next; }
     }
 
     private Node _head = null;
     private bool _isEmpty;
 
     public ConcurrentStackL()
     {
         _head = new Node(default(T), _head);
         _objLock = new object();
         _isEmpty = true;
     }
 
     
 
     public void Push(T item)
     {
         lock (_objLock)
         {
             _head = new Node(item, _head);
             if (!_isEmpty)
                 _isEmpty = false;
         }
     }
 
     public T Pop()
     {
         T item;
         lock (_objLock)
         {
             if (_head._next == null)
                 throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Stack is empty");
 
              item = _head._item;
             _head = _head._next;
 
             if (_head._next == null)
                 _isEmpty = true;
         }
          
         return item;
     }
 }
```

Comment: There is no ordering when two threads are running concurrency. Therefore, there is nothing to preserve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From My Understanding of mutexes and concurrent locks yes it should preserve the ordering. As far as I am aware that when you lock a mutex another thread cannot also lock that mutex and proceed. As a result it stops its execution until the mutex is unlocked and it can continue. The fact that 2 threads cannot access the stack at the same time and the second thread is forced to wait should preserve the order of pops and pushes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want strict FIFO ordering for threads approaching a `synchronized` block, you will not get it with intrinsic locks like you have here.  That is if many threads a waiting for `synchronized(_objLock)` to be available, a thread that arrives later may enter the block before one that arrived earlier.

This is called thread barging and is permitted as intrinsic locking is *unfair*.  If you want a *fair* lock than you would need to use `new ReentrantLock(true)` where true indicates the lock is fair.

What the locking here gives you is the assurance that any thread which is in the synchronized block will be the only thread executing.  That is, the order of push and pop will be preserved for each thread as it sees the stack in the current state.